# Add and execute set of scripts to package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, npm-scripts

I'm new to Node.js, and I need to add a set of scripts to package.json and execute one by one, as explain below. May I need to know is it possible with Node.js?

```
"scripts": {
    "sample": "run --spec '*spec.js'",
    "CB":{
      "Test1": "Test one com",
      "Test2": "Test two com"
    }
  },
```

I can execute the "sample" command using "`npm run sample`."

My Question how to run "Test1"? And is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run multiple scripts by the `&&` operator. For example:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
    "test": "jest",
    "ci-test": "npm run lint && npm run test",
  }
}
```

`npm run ci-test` will execute the `lint` and `test` script.

Nested scripts like in your example are not supported.

But you could do the following:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "sample": "run --spec '*spec.js'",
    "CB.Test1": "Test one com",
    "CB.Test2": "Test two com"
  }
}
```

So you can call for example `npm run CB.Test1`.

See [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts).

Comment: My Question how to run "Test1"? And is it possible? For an example "npm run CB.Test1"

Comment: No, nested scripts / objects are not supported. But see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Objects/Arrays are not supported for scripts. You have to go with a String. Which means you'll have to go with adding line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, but you should break two commands like that under scripts tags. There can be two ways to want to run theses commands : `concurrently` or `sequentially` based on the requirement.

If you want to run them concurrenly make these changes first to the package.json:

```
npm i --save concurrently
```

```
"scripts": {
    "sample": "run --spec '*spec.js'",
    "CB":{ "concurrently \"command1 arg\" \"command2 arg\""}
  },
```

```
npm run CB
```

If the second script is based on the first and want to run sequentially using [run-s](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/tree/bf91f94ce597aa61da37d2e4208ce8c48bc86673), you can do something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "sample": "run --spec '*spec.js'",
      "Test1": "Test one com",
      "Test2": "Test two com"
  },
```

```
run-s Test1 Test2
```

You can check there documentation here: [Concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently#readme) and [npm-run-all](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently#readme).